# Could not locate named parameter [longitude], expecting one of [searchTerm] when using Spring JPA and QueryDSL

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

My JPA query seems to return the correct results, but still throws:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate named parameter [longitude], expecting one of [searchTerm]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.ParameterMetadataImpl.getNamedParameterDescriptor(ParameterMetadataImpl.java:229) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.ParameterMetadataImpl.getQueryParameter(ParameterMetadataImpl.java:198) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingsImpl.getBinding(QueryParameterBindingsImpl.java:188) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameter(AbstractProducedQuery.java:490) ~[hibernate-core-5
```

My JpaRepository has this method:

```
  String HAVERSINE_FORMULA_IMPROVED = "(0.000621371 * 6378137 * 2 * atan2("
      + "      sqrt(sin(radians(c.geonamesPostal.latitude - :latitude) / 2) * sin(radians(c.geonamesPostal.latitude - :latitude) / 2)"
      + "          + cos(radians(:latitude)) * cos(radians(c.geonamesPostal.latitude))"
      + "              * sin(radians(c.geonamesPostal.longitude - :longitude) / 2) * sin(radians(c.geonamesPostal.longitude - :longitude) / 2)),"
      + "      sqrt(1 - sin(radians(c.geonamesPostal.latitude - :latitude) / 2) * sin(radians(c.geonamesPostal.latitude - :latitude) / 2)"
      + "          + cos(radians(:latitude)) * cos(radians(c.geonamesPostal.latitude))"
      + "              * sin(radians(c.geonamesPostal.longitude - :longitude) / 2) * sin(radians(c.geonamesPostal.longitude - :longitude) / 2))))";

  @Query("SELECT c FROM Classified c where c.dateDeleted is NULL and c.title like %:searchTerm% or c.description like %:searchTerm% ORDER BY "
      + HAVERSINE_FORMULA_IMPROVED)
  Page<Classified> findNearestClassifieds(@Param("latitude") double latitude,
      @Param("longitude") double longitude, @Param("searchTerm") String searchTerm, Pageable page);
```

My guess is there is something wrong with the way I'm constructing the @Query

Comment: Have you tried not concatenating HAVERSINE_FORMULA_IMPROVED to the query?

Comment: Yes, adding the text from HAVERSINE_FORMULA_IMPROVED directly to the @Query("... give the same result.

Answer (score 0):

did you find a solution to this?    I had by Haversine function working within a query fine but now, after updating to Spring 3.0 (and corresponding hibernate libs etc) I get this same error (Could not locate named parameter [longitude]).

If I change by function from:

```
String HAVERSINE_PART = " (6371 * " +
        " acos( cos(radians(:latitude)) " +
        "     * cos(radians(ii.latitude)) " +
        "     * cos(radians(ii.longitude) - radians(:longitude)) " +
        "     + sin(radians(:latitude)) " +
        "     * sin(radians(ii.latitude)) ) ) ";
```

to

```
String HAVERSINE_PART = "  (6371 * :longitude + :latitude )" ;
```

I don't get the error.   There seems to be a limit on the complexity of the SQL that JPA can handle.

HAVERSINE_PART is contained as both a select column and within tthe WHERE clause of the SQL Statement.

Comment: Pardon me, but it's not clear (to me, at least) whether you are answering the question or simply saying that you have the same problem. So does changing the value of `HAVERSINE_PART` actually solve the problem?